# Садко

Tags: этимология, ономастика

У героя всем известной сказки Садко — это имя, прозвище или фамилия? И, если имя, то от какого слова она происходит (оно ведь должно быть славянским)?
И, кстати, исходя из того, что женские имена на Руси появились гораздо позже мужских, можно сделать вывод, что сказка эта довольно новая (там ведь есть персонаж Любава).

Comment: ***785** пишет:*

> женские имена на Руси появились
> гораздо позже мужских

Можно поинтересоваться, откуда такая информация? Имена, кажется, это такая древняя штука, что и у дикарей есть. А что же было тогда у женщин в старину на Руси? Любопытно.

Comment: Это достаточно известный факт. Только его надо понимать правильно.  Речь идёт об общественных именах, тех, которыми пользовались в обществе. Таких имен у женщин действительно не было (за исключением княжеских - да и то лишь в отдельных случаях). После княгини Ольги вспоминается только Анна Яросклавна, которая королева Франции. А это полтора века русской истории.  
В остальныз случаях использовались по преимуществу отчества, реже - "придуманные" имена, достоверность которых весьма сомнительна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Любаву не заостряйтесь, это персонаж оперы, в оригинальных сказаниях её нет. 
Это во-первых.

Во-вторых, хотя сюжет сказки не привязывается к конкретному времени, можно заключить, что дело происходит в довольно поздний период (не ранее конца XII века, тогда с рапространением христианства женские имена уже вошли в оборот). И вообще, тут не совсем точно сказано. Какие-то имена у женщин были всегда, но как бы неофициальные. Они употреблялись внутри семьи и за её пределами не были известны.

Что же касается имени Садко, то это, конечно, нецерковное имя, оно же прозвище. Достоверных сведений об этимологии имени нет, не совсем даже ясно, было ли оно в "оригинальной" весии сказаний или появилось много позже.

*Древнейшей основой былины о Садко была, вероятно, песня об историческом лице по имени «Содко Сытинець» (или «Сотко Сытиничь»), упоминаемом в летописи[какой?] под 1167 годом в качестве строителя церкви Бориса и Глеба в Детинце в Новгороде. К имени этого лица приурочены различные сказочные мотивы, восходящие частью к местным легендам, частью к международным бродячим сказочным сюжетам. Так, в новгородских и ростовских легендах упоминается о спасении гибнувшего и плывущего на доске человека; по русским народным верованиям, св. Никола слывёт скорым помощником на водах и даже называется «морским» и «мокрым».*
(Вики)

По одной из версий (также приводимой в Вики) прослеживается связь сказаний о Садко со старофранцузским эпосом, более того, герой там носит созвучное имя. Из этого делается вывод о возможном существовании какого-то общего первоисточника, но мне такое кажется весьма сомнительным в силу ограниченности контактов. 
Дальнейшие подробности, надеюсь, не потребуются.

Answer (score 0):

Имя Садко очень созвучно с именем Садок (Шах-Дуст), по всей видимости это оно и есть,  имя персидское. Известный человек с таким именем - священномученик Садок (Шах-Дуст) родом из Персии, память 1 ноября н.ст.. Наиболее вероятно, что к нам это имя пришло вместе с христианством.

Comment: И как его в Новгород (если не в Олонец!) занесло?

Comment: Священномученика Садока, епископа Персидского и с ним 128 мучеников (ок. 342-344) память 5 февраля (20 февраля ст. ст.)

Comment: Вообще-то по григорианскому календарю — 5 марта (разница — 13 дней).

Answer (score 0):

Садко
«Садко́ (Богатый гость) — герой былин новгородского цикла; из девяти известных вариантов, записанных исключительно в Олонецкой губернии» [ВП]
«Происхождение имени 
От древнееврейского имени צָדוֹק (Цадок) - "праведный". В Ветхом Завете есть несколько персонажей с таким именем, самый известный из которых - Садок, сын Ахитува, первосвященник, помазавший на царство Соломона. В православных и католических святцах также упоминается Садок, епископ Персидский. К нему принято обращаться с молитвами об избежании безвременной смерти».
Источник: http://kurufin.ru/html/Translate/sadko.html»
Согласно былине Садко гусляр, благодаря выигрышу спора об заклад вложил деньги в коммерцию, разбогател и стал купцом. Не исключено, что среди купцов были люди из еврейской диаспоры на новгородском севере, отсюда имя Цадок от саддукеев, купцов из Палестины.
«Саддукеи [греч. Saddukaioi, евр. цедоким, от имени Цадок (Садок), первосвященника 10 в. до н. э.], религиозно-политическое течение в Иудее во 2 в. до н. э. - 1 в. н. э., опиравшееся на жреческую, землевладельческую и военную знать, высшее чиновничество и богатое купечество. С. захватили командные позиции в храмовом культе и политической жизни, став политической опорой династии Хасмонеев.» [БСЭ]
Известна связь иудеев и филистимлян (пелештий, пеласгов - предков славян).
Поэтому имя Цадок могло произойти от славянского слова «сундук», т.е. накопитель денег.
Садко – Цадок – Sadko/Cadok > sunduk – сундук (пропуск n)
Отсюда имя Садко через Цадок славянское Сундук.
Корневое слово от «Садок» - сундук (слав)